# Python: Waking MacOS Device

Tags: python, macos, sleep, wakeup

There is a section in my Python code that requires the MacBook to be awake.
Right before that section, I want include some code that can wake my MacBook up.
Can this be done, or, is it impossible to wake a Mac device inside a Python script?

```
def wake_macbook_up():
    need code here


def code_that_needs_macbook_to_be_awake():
    my current code


wake_macbook_up()
code_that_needs_macbook_to_be_awake()
```

Comment: I do not think you can trivially tell your mac to wake up, but the [caffeine module](https://pypi.org/project/caffeine/) may solve your problem.

Comment: @MrR I am really hoping that a solution exists that will preserve my mac's battery life... thank you for suggesting the caffeine module regardless. I was only aware of the caffeine app.